# Multiple User Input Error Messages (while loop) in Java

Tags: java, error-handling, while-loop, user-input

I'm trying to get the machine to print an error message whenever incorrect data is entered. The two types of error messages are displayed when the user provides

1. either non-numeric value, or
2. negative value.

I'm only able to print the error message if the user enters non-numeric value, but not negative value. I want to write code for error messages to be printed if the user enters wrong grades, but I am still stuck at step 1.  Where should I place the code for it in the following program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab7errortesting {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of grades: ");
        if (!input.hasNextDouble()) {

            System.out.println("***Error: Entered a non-numeric data. Please enter numeric data.");
            input.next();   

        } else {

            double random = input.nextDouble();

            double min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            double max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            double total=0;
            int count = 1;
            while (count < random+1) {


                System.out.println("Enter grade " + count + ":");

                double grade = input.nextDouble();
                total+=grade;

                count++;

                if (max > grade){       

                    max = grade;

                }
                if (min < grade){
                    min = grade;
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Total is " + total);
            System.out.println("Average is " + (total/random));
            System.out.println("Smallest number is " + max);
            System.out.println("Largest number is " + min);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to do but if you just want to filter out all negative *grades* then you could try this:

```
//...
double grade = input.nextDouble();
if (grade < 0){
    System.err.println("Not a valid grade");
    continue;
}
total += grade;
count++;
//..
```

this will print out an error message and prompt the user for a new number if it was negative. So you just check if the entered number was negative an if that's the case it will go back to the beginning of the loop using `continue` without changing `total` or incrementing `count`.